# Counting frequency of a character returns 0 always

Tags: c

I have written a C function that will count the frequency of each character in a char array. The program works, however when I run it using the given test code, I get 0 for the frequencies, however if I were to run it in my own solution, I get the correct answer.

Here is my code.

```
void countchars(const char *array, unsigned int *counts)
{
    int c = 0;
    int k = 0;
    while (array[c] != '\0')
     {
        if (array[c] >= 'a' && array[c] <= 'z' )
        {
            counts[array[c]-'a']++;
        }
        c++;

        if ( array[k] >= 'A' && array[k] <= 'Z' )
        {
             counts[array[c]-'A']++;
        }
        k++;
            
        
    }
}
```

here is the print function I was given.

```
void printcounts(int min, int max, const unsigned int *counts) {
    for (int i = min; i <= max; i++) {
        printf("%c: %u  ---  ", i, counts[i]);
        if ((i - min + 1) % 6 == 0)
            printf("\n");
    } 
}
```

Here is the main function using them both.

```
int main(void)
{
    unsigned int counts[256] = { 0 };

    char sample[] = { 'a','b','r','a','c','a','d','a','b','r','a',0 };

    countchars(sample, counts);
    printcounts('a', 'z', counts);

    return 0;
}
```

This is the output I get when using the given printcounts.

```
a: 0  ---  b: 0  ---  c: 0  ---  d: 0  ---  e: 0  ---  f: 0  ---  
g: 0  ---  h: 0  ---  i: 0  ---  j: 0  ---  k: 0  ---  l: 0  ---  
m: 0  ---  n: 0  ---  o: 0  ---  p: 0  ---  q: 0  ---  r: 0  ---  
s: 0  ---  t: 0  ---  u: 0  ---  v: 0  ---  w: 0  ---  x: 0  ---  
y: 0  ---  z: 0  ---
```

And here is the expected output

```
a: 5  ---  b: 2  ---  c: 1  ---  d: 1  ---  e: 0  ---  f: 0  ---  
g: 0  ---  h: 0  ---  i: 0  ---  j: 0  ---  k: 0  ---  l: 0  ---  
m: 0  ---  n: 0  ---  o: 0  ---  p: 0  ---  q: 0  ---  r: 2  ---  
s: 0  ---  t: 0  ---  u: 0  ---  v: 0  ---  w: 0  ---  x: 0  ---  
y: 0  ---  z: 0  ---
```

Comment: In `countchars`, `c` and `k` always operate in tandem, so why not have only one? -- Your bug probably has to do with the fact that you increment `c` before the upper case test, but you still use `c` in that logic where you probably meant to use `k`.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError ok, so I tried your suggestion, replaced `k` with `c` and incremented `c` after both the checks are done. It's still giving me the same result.

Comment: You should only increment `c` once per iteration, otherwise you'll consider upper and lower case for only every other character in the string.

Comment: Try using `printcounts(0, 'z', counts);` for more information.

Comment: cyberbemon If input was "123", should the `'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'` count as characters that should be counted  and reported or is just letters A-Z,a-z of interest?

Comment: cyberbemon If input was "Aa", should a report of  `printcounts('a', 'z', counts);` say `a: 2` or `a: 1`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica So far the test cases are either all uppercase or lowercase. So I don't think the mixed option is considered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The Problems:

1. In the printcounts function, `counts[]` is read from index 97 ('a') to 122 ('z') at `printcounts('a', 'z', counts);` while frequencies are stored starting from `counts[0]`.
2. Frequency of both Uppercase and Lowercase letters are stored at same array locations.

### The Solution:

You have already taken an array large enough to store frequencies of each ASCII character.

> `unsigned int counts[256] = { 0 };`

Now all you have to do is to increment `counts[character]` by 1 each time a character is encountered. There is no need to define a range of characters to work with and start filling from `counts[0]`.

*Note: This will count frequencies of **all** ASCII characters.*

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    void countchars(const char *array, unsigned int *counts)
    {
        int c = 0;
        while (array[c] != '\0')
         {
            ++counts[(unsigned char)array[c]];
            c++;
         }
     }

    void printcounts(int min, int max, const unsigned int *counts)
    {
        for (int i = min; i <= max; i++)
        {
            printf("%c: %u  ---  ", i, counts[i]);
            if ((i - min + 1) % 6 == 0)
                printf("\n");
        } 
    }

    int main(void)
    {
        unsigned int counts[256] = { 0 };
    
        char sample[] = { 'a','b','r','a','c','a','d','a','b','r','a',0 };
    
        countchars(sample, counts);
        printcounts('a', 'z', counts);
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Done. Thanks for pointing out.  
My compiler had given out warnings but I had overlooked those.

Answer (score 1):

With this:

```
counts[array[c]-'a']++;
```

you are substracting an offset ('a'). There is no offset. Use this instead:

```
counts[array[c]]++;
```

Your second `if` is buggy. You don't need any `k` variable, just use `i` before incrementing it.

Answer (score 0):

The print function you present anticipates that any given character is *itself* the index of the corresponding count, but that's not how your `countchars` function is storing the counts.  Compare

> ```
>             counts[array[c]-'a']++;
> ```

to

> ```
>         printf("%c: %u  ---  ", i, counts[i]);
> ```

.  Since you say the print function was given to you, I presume that you are not permitted to modify it.  In that event, you must update `countchars` to store the counts for each character at the correct index.  It appears that for lowercase letters that would be `array[c]`, as opposed to `array[c]-'a'`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are writing values to the `counts` array than you are not reading from, because they are in different places in the array.

For example, the very first character processed in your array is 'a'. And the following code gets executed:

```
counts[array[c]-'a']++;
```

The char value of `array[c]` is 'a' (which is 97 in ASCII). Subtracting 'a' from 'a' (or 97 from 97) will result in 0. So `counts[0]` is now incremented to the value of 1.

In the `printcounts` function you provided, you never look at `counts[0]` because the min value you pass in is 'a', which is 97.

As the code is written, you will increment values in `counts` from index 0 through 25, but will only read from `counts` from index 97 ('a') to 122 ('z') in your call `printcounts('a', 'z', counts);`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to initialize a variable to store the frequency of characters

```
     string frequency[26];

     for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
     {
          frequency[i] = 0;
     }
```

And then, iterate a string to count frequency of character

```
     for (int j = 0; array[j] != '\0'; j++)
     {
          if (isupper(array[j] != 0)
          {
               frequency[array[j] - 65]++;
          }

          else if (islower(array[j] != 0)
          {
               frequency[array[j] - 97]++;
          }
      }
```